# Updating a column with 1 updates it with 2

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit confused. I have a website with a sort of user-profiles. When a visitor hits a user-page I want to update the number of views by a date and userid. But, no matter what i do, the number of views is updated with 2 instead of one. I've created an query-output for all queries which are executed during a page-request. The update-query is correct and there's only 1 update-query executed during the page-request.

This is my data-structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ProfileView` (
  `Id` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `UserId` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Views` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`,`Date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

No matter what I do, the column 'Views' is always updated by 2 instead of 1.

The logic being executed (called from a controller, controller gets called from the view. Decorator is basically a sealed stdClass providing strict coding guidance because misspelled properties result in a PropertyDoesntExistException):

Workflow:

```
# user-details.php
$oControllerProfileView = new Controller_ProfileView();
$oControllerProfileView->Replace($iUserId);

---    

# Controller.ProfileView.php
public function Replace($iUserId) {
  // validation
  Model_ProfileView::Replace($iUserId, date('Y-m-d'));
}

---

# Model.ProfileView.php
static public function Replace($iUserId, $sDate) {

    $oData = MySQL::SelectOne("
        SELECT  Views
        FROM    ProfileView
        WHERE   UserId = ".$iUserId."
        AND     Date = '".$sDate."'");

    if(is_a($oData, 'Decorator')) {

        MySQL::Query("
            UPDATE  ProfileView
            SET     `Views` = ".($oData->Views + 1)."
            WHERE   UserId = ".$iUserId."
            AND     Date = '".$sDate."'");  
    } else {

        MySQL::Query("
            INSERT INTO ProfileView
            VALUES  (
                NULL,
                ".$iUserId.",
                '".$sDate."',
                1
            )");
    }
}
```

Comment: check server side - enable query logs in your mysql server and see what it is really executing. Comment `UPDATE` query out and see if it is not updated or maybe update by 1 still....

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have acces to MySQL logs on the server.

Comment: Made sure there's nothing else in your controller calling this?  Whether directly or indirectly?  If not, I would see if you could echo $oData->Views + 1 and see if it's correct.

Comment: And thereby, when I query/check the db-records, e.g. 14 gets updated to 16 instead of 15.

Comment: Query is correct, checked it as one of the first things I did, after that I displayed all queries which are being executed during a page-rq.

Comment: ok. if you comment it out as I suggested it is not increased, right? you can also log the `debug_backtrace()` in this method to check who is calling it

Comment: This is the only query being made (in reference to the problem): `UPDATE ProfileView SET Views = 38 WHERE UserId = 3 AND Date = '2012-11-20'`. I found a similar case on the net (http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general/10bvwh64jd/php-add-1-mysql-updates-by-2) but that link isn't providing much info.